# Mysql count result in "where" clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I'm facing a little problem with mysql `where` clause. 
This is the query:

```
SELECT u.id user
     , p.id product_purchased
     , p.name product_name
     , pl.store_id store
     , COUNT(*) occurrences
     , total_spent
     , total_product_purchased
     , pl.registration 
  FROM purchases_log pl 
  JOIN user u 
    ON pl.user_id = u.id 
  JOIN product p 
    ON pl.product_id = p.id
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT user_id
            , SUM(price) total_spent
            , COUNT(product_id) total_product_purchased 
         FROM purchases_log pl 
        GROUP 
           BY user_id
     ) t1 
    ON u.id = t1.user_id
 WHERE pl.store_id IN (1,2,3) 
   AND occurrences > 1 
 GROUP 
    BY user
     , product_name
 ORDER 
    BY u.id ASC
     , pl.registration ASC;
```

This is the output error:

**Error Code: 1054**. Unknown column 'occurrences' in 'where clause'    0.067 sec

I have already tried assign `AS` to occurrences or using pl.
So, can someone explain me how to correctly define the result of a count function in where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `HAVING` instead of `COUNT` as group by is applied after `WHERE` clause and hence, it won't know about any group/aggregate columns, e.g/:

```
SELECT u.id user,p.id product_purchased, p.name product_name,  pl.store_id store, COUNT(*) AS occurrences, total_spent, total_product_purchased, pl.registration 
FROM purchases_log pl 
JOIN user u ON pl.user_id=u.id 
JOIN product p ON pl.product_id=p.id
JOIN (SELECT user_id, SUM(price) AS total_spent,COUNT(product_id) AS total_product_purchased FROM purchases_log pl GROUP BY user_id) t1 ON u.id=t1.user_id
WHERE pl.store_id IN (1,2,3) 
GROUP BY user, product_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY u.id ASC, pl.registration ASC;
```

**Update**

- If a user has more than one product associated then it's good to add all the non aggregate columns in `GROUP BY` to get all the combinations of user and product. The current query will not return all the combinations.
- For further optimization, as @strawberry has suggest, you can run `EXPLAIN` and see which indices are used and whether there is any need to create any new index.

Comment: @UgoL you can accept the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: Yeah, I need to wait 10 minutes for accept it. Meantime I wanna ask you if the query structure looks good or not. Is there any way for optimize it better?

Comment: @UgoL The query looks sensible. For further help on optimization, we would need to see SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables as well as the EXPLAIN for the query.

Comment: @UgoL you might need to include all the `non aggregated` columns into `GROUP BY` if the relation is one to many between user and product.

Comment: Can you please add in the answer also the query with this tips? So I can test it.